# multiple channels over tcp?

Tags: java, c, tcp, protocols

i want to know if there is an existing communication protocol based on top of TCP/IP that handles multiple channels (each with in+out stream).

Languages:

- Java
- C for embedded devices, ideally based on lwIP

Features:

- Multiple channels, each with a stream for in and out.
- Each out stream can be flushed to ensure all content is sent.
- If one stream blocks (not read by receiver), the other streams go still on.
- configurable buffering support 
  (e.g. Channel 1: 100Kb, Channel 2: 2000kB), 
  like if receiver stops reading one stream, the writing on the sender 
  side is blocked.
- Implementation available as open source and for commercial use.

Is there something already existing?

thanks
Frank

Comment: Normally you would use a socket for each channel as it does everything you have mentioned here. perhaps you can indicate a requirement which means multiple connections is not possible?

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP means 'multiple virtual connections hosted on top of single server<>client TCP connections', but yes, it's not really clear...

Comment: I want to avoid multiple sockets to save resources like memory/port-numbers/interrupts.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, there is a protocol called [BEEP](http://beepcore.org/) that offers several of these features. I don't know whether anybody actually uses it or not.

> BEEP is not a protocol for sending and receiving data directly. Rather, it allows you to define your application protocol on top of it, reusing several mechanisms such as: asynchronous communications, transport layer security, peer authentication, channel multiplexing on the same connection, message framing, channel bandwidth management, and many more interesting network features.